# How to validate xlsx File Header Name and column value for each header in java using apache poi?

Tags: java, spring

How i can validate xlsx file header as well as row?
Suppose there will be 10 column,I want some column should be Integer and some column should be String.If any validation fail then that file should not be proceed ,If all validation pass then we need to update record into our table based on meterno and boundary_id.
If meterno and boundary_id combination is not present for some record then,it should not be insert into our table.For those we need to create new xlsx file(Not Update record) and save into our local directory.

Note:-CT,PT,MF should be Number and rest all string.

Please find attache xlsx file.

[image: XLSX file screen shoot]

```
@Controller
public class UploadExeclController {

     // all key value pair mapping (  holding column name and its respective value per row.
    Map<String,Object>  records =  new HashMap<String,Object>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadBoundaryFile", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public @ResponseBody void uploadBoundaryFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            ModelMap model) {
        try {

            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
            MultipartFile myFile = multipartRequest.getFile("fileUpload");

            String fileName = myFile.getOriginalFilename();
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(getTempFile(myFile));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            // GET the header row
            Row headerRow = sheet.getRow(0);
            // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
            //Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();


            // LIst of headers from excel
            List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
            Iterator<Cell> cells = headerRow.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next();
                RichTextString value = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                headers.add(value.getString());
            }
         // validate the template 
            Object[] headerValidation = validateTempalte(headers);

            // if validation fails then write back the message to user.
            if((Boolean) headerValidation[0]==false){
                List<String> headerValidationMsg = (List<String>) headerValidation[1];
                return ;
            }
         // Assign a number to header.This is done so that when we reading excel value we can identiy the cell value belongs to which column 
            Map<String,Integer> headerSeqNumber = assignHeaderSeqNumber(headers);


          //Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
            int rowNumber=0;
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                if(rowNumber==0){
                    rowNumber++;
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Row no "+rowNumber);
                Iterator<String> columnsIterator = headerSeqNumber.keySet().iterator();
                while (columnsIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String name = columnsIterator.next();
                    System.out.println("Read columnName "+name);
                    int cellType=row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getCellType();
                    switch (cellType) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        RichTextString value= row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getRichStringCellValue();
                        String val=value!=null ?value.getString().trim():null;
                        val=val.replaceAll(":", "");
                        val=val.replaceAll("'", "");
                        records.put(name,val);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)))) {
                            Date date = row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getDateCellValue(); 
                        //    records.put(name,Utils.convertDateToString(date, "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
                        }else{
                            double numericVal= row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getNumericCellValue();
                            records.put(name,numericVal);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        System.err.println(" blank cell type ");
                        records.put(name,null);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.err.println(" NEither string no number "+row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getCellType());
                        System.err.println(" value "+row.getCell(headerSeqNumber.get(name)).getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }

                }
                // once a row is read validate each cell 
                Object[]  validationResults=validateRecords(records);
                Boolean isDataValid =(Boolean) validationResults[0];

                List<String> vMessages =new ArrayList<String>();
                // if data is valid then update the value in db.
                if (isDataValid) {
                    System.out.println(" Valid data sending for upating record");
                   // String msg = executeProcedure(records);
                   //  vMessages.add(msg);
                }else{
                    // if there is validation issues then add the messages to list.
                    if(validationResults[1]!=null){
                        vMessages = (List<String>) validationResults[1];
                    }
                    System.err.println(" data is invalid");
                }
               // errorMessages.put(rowNumber, vMessages);
                rowNumber++;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }






    public File getTempFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        CommonsMultipartFile commonsMultipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) multipartFile;
        FileItem fileItem = commonsMultipartFile.getFileItem();
        DiskFileItem diskFileItem = (DiskFileItem) fileItem;
        String absPath = diskFileItem.getStoreLocation().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(absPath);

        // trick to implicitly save on disk small files (<10240 bytes by default)
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                multipartFile.transferTo(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Do you just want to validate the cell type?

Comment: Cell Type as well as their value (column name and their value) @deHaar

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly is not working in your code? It's a lot of code for a single question, by the way...

Comment: column name and their value validation @deHaar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CellType type = cell.getCellType();` to check whether its numeric or string.

```
                    CellType type = cell.getCellType();
                    if (type == CellType.STRING) {
                        // your job which needs to be done
                    }
```

*If meterno and boundary_id combination is not present for some record* , for this condition just write null check or some logic once you have implemented the logic mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Posting method implementation which can validate every cell value of a particular row, let's say Header in this case. Based on validation rule can store validation errors to respond.

```
private Map<String, ProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail> validateCpiDataFile(MultipartFile file) {
    Map<String, ProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> headerNames = Arrays.asList("Index", "Portfolio", "Time Period", "Year");
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    if (Objects.isNull(file) && file.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorCode(), service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorMessage());
    } else {
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook cpiWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
            Sheet sheet = cpiWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int colCount = 0;
            int cellCount = sheet.rowIterator().next().getLastCellNum() - sheet.rowIterator().next().getFirstCellNum();
            if (cellCount == headerNames.size()) {
                for (Cell cell : sheet.getRow(0)) {
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell); // from apache poi 5.2.0 on
                    if (!headerNames.get(colCount).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue.trim())) {
                        ProductDetailResponse.ErrorDetail error = new ProductDetailResponse
                                .ErrorDetail(ProductDetailResponse.ValidationsType.INVALID_HEADER.getValue(), cell.getRowIndex(), "Header Value and Order is mismatched with specified format.");
                        errorMap.put(cellValue, error);
                    }
                    colCount++;
                }
            } else {
                log.error("Number of column mismatched from specified format. Please verify file headers.");
                throw new Exception(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorCode(), service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorMessage());
            }

        } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            log.error("Exception at validateCpiDataFile() while validating CPI data file. Exception: [{}]", e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorCode(), service.getErrorProperties().getCpiFileUploadErrorMessage());
        }
    }
    return errorMap;
}
```